# how find the most common tokens in 2 columns of a data frame where the first column has many items?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 columns. for each element in a column `col2`  I want to search in `col1` to see which element of `col2` has the most common token with the element of `col1`?

```
Example:

key     col1                                                         col2
ab    'summer hot, best friend, not possible, apple, let it go'      "let be hot"
cd     'do it better', 'I am sa'                                     "I need to go"
fg      'my best post, fun sunday'                                   "it's great"
```

output

```
key     col1                                                         col2            match
ab    'summer hot, best friend, not possible, apple, let it go'    "let be hot"    "let it go"
cd     'do it better, I am sa'                                  "I need it do sa"    "I am sa"
fg      'my best post, fun sunday'                                    "it's great"       None
```

the first row has a common token with both `summer hot` and `let it go` but it dosn't matter which one is selected.

I did the following but i am looking for a more efficient method:

```
name_norm=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    name_max_tok=''
    max_tok=0
    for l in df['col1'].values[i].split(' '):
        count=0
        for k in df['col2'].values[i].split(' '):
            if k in l:
                count=count+1
            if max_tok<count:
                max_tok=count
                name_max_tok=l
    name_norm.append(name_max_tok)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['ab',    'summer hot, best friend, not possible, apple, let it go',      "let be hot"],
['cd',     'do it better, I am sa',                                     "I need to go"],
['fg',      'my best post, fun sunday' ,                                  "it's great"],
], columns=['key', 'col1', 'col2'])
df["col2_set"] = df["col2"].apply(lambda x: set(x.split(" ")))
def setter(x):
    data = x.col1.split(",")
    res = np.array([len(x.col2_set.intersection(y.split(" "))) for y in data])
    if res.sum() == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return data[res.argmax()]
df['match'] = df.apply(lambda x: setter(x), axis=1)
df.drop(columns=['col2_set'], inplace=True)
df
```

Comment: just wondering could u convert it to pyspark ?

Comment: @user15649753 no... I'm learning pyspark and at first of the way and I think you must ask it again and this time with `pyspark` tag...